# A lot of problems with IE 9, datagrid, TabContainer, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-7, datagrid

I'm having several problems with IE 9, so the first is the DataGrid Button column is not firing and in Chrome works ok, then the TabContainer is not displaying at all, also in chrome does, what could it be?

```
<tr>
<td>
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgOficios2" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" 
    ondeletecommand="dgOficios2_DeleteCommand" 
    oneditcommand="dgOficios2_EditCommand" 
    OnSortCommand="dgOficios2_SortCommand"
    OnItemDataBound="dgOficios_Bound" >
            <EditItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#C1D0EC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0B63A2" ForeColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:EditCommandColumn CancelText="Cancel" EditText="Editar" UpdateText="Update" Visible="false">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                </asp:EditCommandColumn>
                <asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Distribuir"></asp:ButtonColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id"
                     Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TypeCCompany" HeaderText="Bloque" SortExpression="TypeCCompany" 
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="DocNum" HeaderText="Número  Oficio" SortExpression="DocNum"
                     Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
                          <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Receiver" HeaderText="Destino" SortExpression="Receiver"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="SigantureDoc" HeaderText="Firma" SortExpression="SigantureDoc"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="SignaturePosition" HeaderText="Puesto" SortExpression="SignaturePosition"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Status" HeaderText="Estatus" SortExpression="Status"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Note" HeaderText="Asunto" SortExpression="Note"
                     Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
                       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Date" HeaderText="Fecha" SortExpression="Date"
                     Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
                       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ReceiverDate" HeaderText="Fecha de Recepcion" SortExpression="ReceiverDate"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ModificationDate" HeaderText="Fecha de Modificacion" SortExpression="ModificationDate"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CreationDate" HeaderText="Fecha de Creacion" SortExpression="CreationDate"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TypeCDocument" HeaderText="TypeCDocument" SortExpression="TypeCDocument"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                         <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Prior" HeaderText="Antecedentes" SortExpression="Prior"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                         <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Consecutive" HeaderText="Consecutivo" SortExpression="Consecutive"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                         <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Letter" HeaderText="Letra" SortExpression="Letter"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                         <asp:BoundColumn DataField="InputOutput" HeaderText="Entrada/Salida" SortExpression="InputOutput"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
                       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RemainderDate" HeaderText="Recordatorio" SortExpression="RemainderDate"
                     Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
</td>
</tr>
```

And the TabContainer:

```
<asp:Content ID="sist" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="formas">

<cc1:TabContainer ID="tbSist" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" >
<cc1:TabPanel ID="tblDestinos" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>Personas de Atencion</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate >

<asp:MultiView ID="mview1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">

<asp:View runat="server">

 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonUsuariosNew2" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonUsuariosNew_Click" Text="Agregar Nuevo"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is driving me insane is done in asp.net, it works in development in both IE6 and IE9, wth microsoft, is in iis7. The cc1 is an AjaxControlToolkit, help?. Thanks

Edit: Yes I have another Datagrid with buttons only this one does work.

```
      <asp:DataGrid ID="dgUsuarios" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" 
    ondeletecommand="dgUsuarios_DeleteCommand" 
    oneditcommand="dgUsuarios_EditCommand" 
    OnSortCommand="dgUsuarios_SortCommand"
     ShowFooter="true" OnItemCommand="doInsert" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50"
     OnPageIndexChanged="pagechange">
            <EditItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#C1D0EC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0B63A2" ForeColor="White" />
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="edit" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/img/editUser.png" Width="16px" Height="16px" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Editar Usuarios" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ToolTip="Eliminar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/deleteUser.png" Height="16px" Width="16px" CausesValidation="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id"
                     Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Usuario" SortExpression="Name" 
                     Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="FullName" Visible="false"
                    ></asp:BoundColumn>
                          <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Position" HeaderText="Puesto" SortExpression="Position" Visible="false"
                   ></asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" Visible="false"
                     ></asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="TypeCDoc" HeaderText="Area" SortExpression="TypeCDoc"
                     Visible="true">                                      
                     </asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Autorizar" HeaderText="Autoriza" SortExpression="Autorizar"
                     Visible="true">                                      
                     </asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Distribuir" HeaderText="Distribuye" SortExpression="Distribuir"
                     Visible="true">                                      
                     </asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Generar" HeaderText="Genera" SortExpression="Generar"
                     Visible="true">                                      
                     </asp:BoundColumn>
                     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Escanear" HeaderText="Escanea" SortExpression="Escanear"
                     Visible="true">                                      
                     </asp:BoundColumn>
                      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LeerTodo" HeaderText="Lee Todo" SortExpression="LeerTodo"
                     Visible="true">                                      
                     </asp:BoundColumn>
                      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password"
                     Visible="false">                                      
                     </asp:BoundColumn>
                      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Enviar" HeaderText="Enviar" SortExpression="Enviar"
                     Visible="true">                                      
                     </asp:BoundColumn>
                     <%--<asp:TemplateColumn >--%>
                    <%-- <ItemTemplate>

                     </ItemTemplate>
                     <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="ls" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     </FooterTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateColumn>--%>
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was a problem with the ie9 for security all javascript was disable, so the events were not firing.